# Are items carried over to a NewGame+?

Tags: demons-souls

So I'm just about to go fight the last Arch Demon in Demon's Souls. Obviously, I know there is a NG+ but are my items carried over into this? If they're not it makes sense to either consume them for their souls or go learn the spells with them before hand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the new game plus page on the [demons souls wiki](http://demonssouls.wikidot.com/newgame-plus):

> **What will be carried over**
>
> The following items will carry over from one NG lifecycle to the subsequent NG lifecycle (e.g. from NG+ to NG++)
>
> - All Consumables and Upgrade Stones. This includes Eye Stones, which enables you to summon phantoms in 1-1
> - All Demon's Souls
> - All Weapons, Armor and Shields
> - All Miracles and Spells, your memorized ones will also remain the same
> - World Tendency
> - Character Tendency
> - Soul Level and Stats
> - Worlds 1-3, 1-4 and False King will be accessible without defeating any Archdemons (after completing 1-1 and 1-2, however)
>
> The items mentioned above include those stored with Stockpile Thomas.
>
> **What will not be carried over**
>
> - All NPCs will reset to their default position, this includes all who have died for whatever reason.
> - All Keys will reset to their default position.
> - All doors and unlockable areas will reset.
>     Note: If you have the World Tendency requirement to open an area such as the execution grounds in 1-1 (Where Miralda is) when you complete the game, upon starting NG+ you will find that area open already. Although the door will have shut when you finished the game, the game will take into account your WT upon starting NG+ and will unlock/open any areas as normal.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, AdamP! I edited it to properly format the quote. For future reference, you can check the formatting of your answers in the preview area below the textbox where you type them in, and the gory formatting details are available [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/editing-help). Hope this helps!